# Julia ccall windows

Tags: c++, julia, libraries

I'm new with Julia and I have one(many) problem(s). I'm using c++ libraries (.dll/.lib) to connect my c++ program to company's program (it connects to home 127.0.0.1 through 5111 port by calling function "connect(port,in, out) and it works). Now I have Julia code that has to the same thing. 
My question is, how can I use this libraries? I try to use ccall function, but it doesn't find those libraries. I haven't found any info on windows how to set different libraries for ccall.

Other option is I translate everything to c++, but...no. Maybe second option is that I open the libraries and re-write them to Julia.

I'm using windows 7 and visual studio for c++. For Julia I use Atom with Juno package.

Comment: Any idea? I found the libraries c++ files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well found the problem... My dll file was 32 and julia was 64. So either install 32-bit version of Julia or get 64-bit version of .dll file to get forward. 
And function finds the file by path:

```
ccall( (:fun, "C:\\Users\\pinq-\\Documents\\Julia\\librarie"), Int32, ())
```